# Hierarchical Query Advantages

Tags: mysql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have some huge database tables filled with scientific names, in a parent-child relationship, like this...

```
TAXON | PARENT
Mammalia | Chordata
Carnivora | Mammalia
Canidae | Carnivora
Canis | Canidae
Canis-lupus | Canis
```

I installed PostgreSQL and started working on a hierarchical query, but it's far more complex than I thought. So I'm thinking of sticking with MySQL and going back to my original scheme, which looks like this:

```
TAXON | PARENT | FAMILY | ORDER
Mammalia | Chordata | (NULL) | (NULL)
Carnivora | Mammalia | (NULL) | Carnivora
Canidae | Carnivora | Canidae | Carnivora
Canis | Canidae | Canidae | Carnivora
Canis-lupus | Canis | Canidae | Carnivora
```

It looks amateurish, but I was surprised to discover that the Catalogue of Life apparently uses the same scheme, with more columns and over a million rows.

With this scheme, I can count children and grandchildren by simply counting the number of species that match Table.Family > Canidae, for example. And I can use a series of "stairstep" queries to figure out the names of the great grandparents, etc.

So I wondered what the benefits of hierarchical queries are. They're more elegant, and you can presumably do everything with just one or two queries, rather than a series of queries. I also assume they're faster, though my original query, with the two extra fields, is fast enough.

Do hierarchical queries have some additional significant advantage that would justify me hiring someone to set one up, or is it primarily just a matter of speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by hierarchical queries, you mean Postgresql [Common Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html); the answer is that they are a wonderfull feature that would allow you to write more readable queries and in some (but not all) cases lead to improved performance.

Is it really worth hiring someone to install postgresql for you? Maybe, maybe not. It's hard to say without benchmarks.

What you really ought to try: is [Modified Pre order Tree Traversal](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) now that sounds complicated, but it isn't

> We’ll start by laying out our tree in a horizontal way. Start at the root node (‘Food’), and write a 1 to its left. Follow the tree to ‘Fruit’ and write a 2 next to it. In this way, you walk (traverse) along the edges of the tree while writing a number on the left and right side of each node. The last number is written at the right side of the ‘Food’ node. In this image, you can see the whole numbered tree, and a few arrows to indicate the numbering order.

Here is another excellent article on it. http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

This approach can be used in both postgreql and mysql and the existing data can be converted without too much difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive / hierarchical query is often actually slower. It varies - there are many more rows, but on the other hand each row is much smaller.

The main advantage is flexibility, rather than performance. In your table you have a set number of columns... but what if there was any number of possible steps between ultimate parent (root) and ultimate child (leaf)? Or branches that join as well as open, so that one object has two parents? That's when hierarchical queries become more useful.